# AWS Gateway timeout

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using a lambda function to process a large amount of data (which exceeds 30s) and I am receicing a message from AWS Gateway:

> Endpoint request timed out

I understand this is obviously because of the default timeout with AWS Gateway, however my Lambda function is set to run for up to 15 minutes.

What is the best way to increase this timeout? Surely this can be done considering lambdas can be set to execute for a much longer time.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API Gateway has a hard limit of 30 seconds. If your lambdas regularly take over 30 seconds (and you really need to use an API endpoint instead of a schedule, SQS or other source), you should use the lambda behind the gateway to trigger another lambda that does the actual work and give a response something like `{ "file_id": "some_id", "status": "in_progress"}`.
Then fetch the result of the work from another API endpoint.
And ideally you should also have another endpoint to check the status of the work so the user of the API knows when it is done and results are ready for download.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sounds like a viable option given their constraints but also ridiculous that I have to implement such a complex architecture just because of a timeout...

Comment: @redhouse87 It would be bad practice to wait up do 15 minutes for an API response. What I described is a common pattern for whenever you need to fetch data from an API that takes longer than a few seconds to compile.

Comment: Normally yes but in this context it's a business analysis tool that exports huge amounts of information. Our users are notified of how long it takes and will usually only export once per day then use that data for analysis, so UX wise the 15 minutes timeout is ok for us

Comment: @redhouse87 That is exactly the use case for this pattern tho. If you want to make it simpler for your users, then you run the worker lambda on a regular schedule (24 hours, or more often if the data needs to be "fresh" all the time) and only give your users the download link.

Comment: @redhouse87 isn't it an option to implement a cache and make sure it is always warm? Another option might be to implement pagination. But both of these options depend on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

API gateway times out after 30 seconds, have you tried using scheduled events to trigger the lambda instead of going through API gateway?

Comment: I still need to provide a URL to a file as a response and seeing as my application does not have a DB this approach would not really be possible

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) API Gateway times out after 30 seconds. And as of now it is not configurable.

> Integration timeout    50 milliseconds - 29 seconds for all integration types, including Lambda, Lambda proxy, HTTP, HTTP proxy, and AWS integrations.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why this is... does Google Cloud have such limits?

Comment: @redhouse87 that is just a hardcoded limitation of API Gateway. Not sure about Google Cloud.

Comment: Yea, really find AWS in general ridiculous. It has terrible UX in general and so many issues and unhelpful errors when trying to create services. If a startup nowadays launched with this many usability issues they would sink. Looking forward to exploring Google Cloud as i've heard they are much more usable in these regards

Comment: Sorry for the rant ;)

Comment: @redhouse87 I feel your pain :)

Comment: @redhouse87 I thought that too when I was starting out with AWS, but then I worked with Azure for a week and couldn't wait to go back to AWS lol. Some things are a bit convoluted at first, and the frontend UI could be more intuitive but once you get used the quirks it's not that bad, and at least the aws cli and sdks are consistent and support almost anything you can imagine unlike Azure. Haven't tried Google Cloud yet tho, but knowing how Google normally does UX and documentation, I doubt it's any better.